# How to show multiple stackoverflow flairs on my website?

Tags: support

Each user on my website has their own SO account. I would like to show each user's SO flair in their profile pages. What is the simplest way to do it?

I tried simply embedding the flair images (like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair)), but I get this problem: the first flair loads fine, but others *fails to load*. I guess it is some kind of limitation by stackoverflow.com. I could download and serve the images from my server, but is there any simpler way?